# Can you help me open my alter user?

Tags: support, user-accounts

My name is Erin Carmody 916. Can you unite me with myself?  Please forgive me for my former transgressions. I promise to show my love for mathoverflow in the way it is intended in the future. I don't know her login, but I know this one 000.

Comment: I sent this to the mathoverflow help.

Comment: If you mean that you have two accounts and want to merge them, see this: http://mathoverflow.net/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 8):

The request to merge was granted (thanks to a StackExchange Community Manager), and the question raised in comments as to whether the MO user named 000 coincides with Erin Carmody has been settled affirmatively to my complete satisfaction.

It should be noted that moderators do not perform account mergers themselves; this is an action taken at the Community Manager level. I am confident that they routinely take care to verify the identities of the accounts, although in response to comments (now deleted), I took an extra step of contacting Erin privately just to be doubly sure.

Erin's procedure to write to 'MO help' is perfectly appropriate and is mentioned in Jeff Atwood's answer here: [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) My own feeling is that any method that is unobtrusive and gets moderator attention (e.g., a flag) is fine for this purpose; I'm all for keeping it simple. Just make clear which account is to be merged into which. All I then do in this situation is pass the request along to my very helpful go-to guy on the SE community team and he takes care of it; you can also go through the official SE contact form channel (https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), but my own experience with this channel is that this can take longer and can be slightly more cumbersome.